# Logitech LUA script: sound not playing

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to make it so that every time I activate a new profile on my Logitech mouse, a few sound files are played so that I know which profile I'm on. But it doesn't seem to work. Anyways here's the code for one of my profiles:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        OutputDebugMessage([[EXE.]] .. [[SoundPlay ( "C:\LUA files\Files that are NOT to be moved\cork-profile_change.wav" )]])
        Sleep(500)
        OutputDebugMessage([[EXE.]] .. [[SoundPlay ( "C:\LUA files\Files that are NOT to be moved\profile_text_format" )]])
    end
end
```

Could you help me figure this out?

Comment: why would it work? I'd imagine that OutputDebugMessage outputs a debug message, not plays a sound

Comment: What application is responsible for processing these `[[EXE.]]` magic messages?  Please give a link to documentation.

Comment: @user253751 - You're correct.  But arbitrary program can read these debug messages.  Moreover, sending/processing such messages  is actually a standard way to integrate your service into LGS.